# Toggle display of a block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table... EACH < tr> has a div with class=opt_NS1, for each tr I have a link with class=d4_0I_oL_vJ where user clicks and the div of THAT < tr> with class=opt_NS1 displays...

here is an example of the table

```
<tr><a class="d4_0I_oL_vJ"></a><div class="opt_NS1"></div></tr>
<tr><a class="d4_0I_oL_vJ"></a><div class="opt_NS1"></div></tr>
<tr><a class="d4_0I_oL_vJ"></a><div class="opt_NS1"></div></tr>
<tr><a class="d4_0I_oL_vJ"></a><div class="opt_NS1"></div></tr>
<tr><a class="d4_0I_oL_vJ"></a><div class="opt_NS1"></div></tr>
<tr><a class="d4_0I_oL_vJ"></a><div class="opt_NS1"></div></tr>
```

Now I wrote this code for the "class="opt_NS1"" to appear on click...

```
jQuery('.d4_0I_oL_vJ').on('click', function (evt) {
    var $button = jQuery(this);
    var $tr = $button.parents('tr');
    var $div = $tr.find('.opt_NS1');
    $div.toggle();
});
```

But the problem I'm having is when I click on one link the div appears normally, but if I click on another link from another tr the new div for that tr appears too but the old one that was opened STILL REMAINS opened... how can I make so when a link of a tr is clicked OTHER "class=opt_NS1" divs get hidden...

Can somebody help me on this please. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery('.d4_0I_oL_vJ').on('click', function (evt) {
    var $button = jQuery(this);
    var $tr = $button.closest('tr');//better change here to closest
    var $div = $tr.find('.opt_NS1');//current div
    jQuery('.opt_NS1').not($div).hide(); //hide all other div's not the current one
    $div.toggle();
});
```

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/%3anot/#not-selector)

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)